# How to add a default route to a DHCP-enabled interface?

Tags: networking, systemd, routing, systemd-networkd

All my servers' networking is configured via DHCP which sends, among others, a static route (needed for a VPN) and a gateway. This works fine.

**I have one exception: a server which should not get the static route** (but get everything else, ideally the gateway as well).

In order to deny the provided route(s), I added to its network config

```
[DHCP]
UseRoutes=false
```

This got rid of the static route (good) and also the default gateway (not good).

Ideally, I would like to receive the gateway from the DHCP server but I am OK to hardcode it in the configuration.

To this I tried several solutions, **all of them failed** (= the default route was not added)

1. Add a `Gateway=` entry in the `[Network]` section:

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
Gateway=192.168.10.1

[DHCP]
UseRoutes=false
```

2. Add an extra route, with something which looks like a "default":

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

[DHCP]
UseRoutes=false

[Route]
Gateway=192.168.10.1
Destination=default
# or, alternatively
# Destination=0.0.0.0/0
```

**How can I add a default route to a DHCP configuration which denies the provided routes?**

In other words, how to make `systemd-networkd` run something equivalent to `ip r add default via 192.168.10.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the `Destination=` directive and it'll be considered a default route.

From the official documentation: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#Destination=

> If omitted, a full-length host route is assumed.

This should work for you:

```
[Route]
Gateway=192.168.10.1
# Nothing else!
```